# Why can't I flag this answer as VLQ?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags, low-quality-posts

When I try to flag [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/957528/1305516)

[image]

the VLQ radio button does not appear, however it does appear for other answers. Why is that?

Comment: It's non-negative, thus not an option. [meta-tag:status-bydesign].

Comment: In this case I don't even think VLQ is the most appropriate response.  This is link-only answer to a question that is asking for a tool.  I think both the answer and the question are candidates for closing (not-an-answer and off-topic respectively).

Comment: @ryanyuyu It is an answer though.

Comment: It's not a link-only answer if you could still determine the answer from the post if the link goes dead. In this case, the question (now closed) asked for products, and the products can be determined from the URLs even without following them. The question is one that doesn't belong on SO anymore, but the answer looks okay to me.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat: No, it's not.

Comment: Gotta love the meta effect with all the DVs.

Comment: the whole question is closed, since its very offtopic. This is a valid answer to a question that shouldn't have been posted. I don't see a reason to touch the answers.

Comment: That stuff is ancient, just let it rest on the votes? Poor guys getting hammered with down votes due to a changing environment...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, it is. (See how useful that response is?)

Comment: @Chris: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95691/155739

Comment: @Lightness: `The name of the module is the most important part of the answer, and it's included directly in the answer, so that's fine. If the answer didn't have the module name in an apparent way, the appropriate reaction would be to edit it,` In this case, the module names are apparent and we should be editing it to be even more obvious, not flagging it as NAA. There's enough information in this answer that even if the links die, you could google for "rabbitmq" and "activemq" and still find the modules.

Comment: Nice work on my 6 year old question, everyone.

Comment: @Joe: Post age is irrelevant. Resistance is futile.

Comment: @ChrisHayes: Feel free to edit it to make it an answer to avoid it being flagged to deletion. In the absence of that charity, it is not an answer and should be flagged as such.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Did you even read what I said? The names are *already apparent*. It's already an answer. The fact that those names happen to be inside of links doesn't make it link-only. On top of which, I'd fully support any mod rejecting a NAA flag on the basis that being too lazy to trivially improve the answer does not justify deleting something that has clearly been helpful to people.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Very Low Quality basically means unsalvagable junk. Abuse, gibberish, or irrelevant nonsense.

It's switched off when something is upvoted, because by the will of the community, it's not junk. (It may not be very good, but that's not the same thing - downvote an answer that's not very good).

This is a link-only-answer which is a flag/close reason in its own right. That would probably be apt for this question - because whilst it probably does answer the question (as much as 'RTFM' might), it's not what Stack Overflow is looking for.

Comment: No, it's not a link-only answer, as I already commented on the question here. A link-only answer is an answer that would become worthless if the link breaks. The answer doesn't become worthless even if the links break.

Comment: @hvd Completely agree, the link-only-answer seems to be a very bright and shiny red herring here. The links explicitly contains the name of the software.

Comment: Yes, fair enough. It's not a link only answer. But neither is it a VLQ, both because it _is_ an answer, and because it has been upvoted.

Comment: Link-only is not one of the available flag reasons.