# Was a "Not an Answer" flag appropriate for this answer?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer, specific-answer

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163434/are-nulls-in-a-relational-database-okay) asks whether storing nulls in a database is okay.

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/163436/3271599) (currently second-highest voted with 43 votes) as *Not An Answer*, as the entirety of the text of the answer reads

> Null markers are fine. Really, they are.

This flag was disputed. Is this actually a good answer? To me, it's just a more verbose version of the one-word answer "Yes."

Comment: It's definitely **not** *"Not an answer"* from a flag perspective - it *does* attempt to answer the question. Whether you think it's a *good* answer is another matter.

Comment: It is an answer, just a low quality answer.

Comment: Back in October of 2008, a few months after the site got started, they had not yet figured out that subjective questions attract subjective answers.  And rather liked subjectivity too much, took a fat year to get that fixed.  Digging up and scrutinizing the Q+A from back then isn't very productive, you'll find plenty of skeletons, it is a historical artifact.

Comment: I don't think that a simple "yes" answer would have garnered 43 votes. That number of votes suggests not merely that it is an answer but that is some sense it is a good answer. The second sentence suggests that the question is an example of misplaced scruples. Obviously more can be said, but the second sentence adds something beyond a mere "yes".

Comment: The question sucks and should be closed.  Ask a crappy question, get a lousy answer.

Comment: I would flag it as low quality post and at review task I would recommend delete because its not really an answer it should be comment of that post.

Comment: It can't be flagged as low quality because it has upvotes

Comment: so downvote is only option now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is an *attempt* at an answer - even if it's a short one-liner with no explanation. It you think it's rubbish - that's what downvotes are for - if you don't have the rep to downvote, then flag as "other" if you think it's serious enough to warrant moderator attention - there's a user base of well over a million users on the site - it'll get noticed eventually :)

On a side note:

No moderator was involved with your flag - NAA's are lower priority on the list - they're usually handled by the community via downvotes etc.. and 20k+ users on SO can then delete those answers via seeing them in the 10k+  tools or coming across them in their frequented tags.

What happened was, the post went through the VLQ queue, while you had an NAA flag still pending, and the system automatically rejected your NAA flag when three users said "OK" in the VLQ.

Using an NAA flag was not appropriate in this case anyway - so it would most likely have ended up declined regardless.

Comment: It seems to be hit-or-miss on whether the VLQ flag is there. I looked at two fresh answers from the front page, one had the flag, one didn't.

Comment: @Aaroninus [If the answer is upvoted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284803/why-cant-i-flag-this-answer-as-vlq/284842#284842) there will not be an option to flag for VLQ. So that's probably why one answer had the flag and the other didn't.

Comment: You're suggesting the people flag bad answers if they don't have the rep to downvote?  Really?  You know better than that.

Comment: And what about this post merits moderator attention?  And you specifically said, "if you don't have enough rep to downvote".  If the post merits moderator attention you should be doing it *regardless of whether you can downvote*.

Answer (score 8):

It's not *great*, but it is an answer to the question - a "not an answer" flag is not appropriate. Downvote it if you think it's not useful.

Answer (score 5):

It's an answer. Really, it is.