# My flag has been declined. Why?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630884/opening-vim-help-in-a-vertical-split-window/4250007#4250007) as **not an answer**, but my flag has been declined, giving the reason "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer".

While the question is about opening the help in vertical window in Vim, the answer is about opening two files, which is not an answer to the question.

This answer definitely doesn't attempt to answer the question.

I need further explanation why **not an answer** flag cannot be used for the declined reason - "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer".

Comment: I think the response you received is clear. Flags aren't for incorrect answers. That's what down votes are for.

Comment: I beg to differ - I think the answer you linked does *attempt* to answer the question, it's just that the answer is very wrong.

Comment: Cool. Thank you. I'll recall your comments in future.

I've an other answer flagged which is likely to be declined, is there a way to reverse the flagging?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister: Can this very wrong answer be flagged "very low quality"?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to revoke a flag AFAIK, but I wouldn't worry too much about it - you seem to have over 50 flags deemed helpful, so you're not spamming them willy nilly or anything. Also from [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284842), "Very Low Quality basically means unsalvagable junk. Abuse, gibberish, or irrelevant nonsense." So IMO the correct action for the answer you linked would be to downvote and not flag. More info on answer deletion can be found [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563).

Comment: That's a lot of information. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It was declined because it is an answer. If the answer is incorrect but an attempt to answer the question, then you should downvote it and if you want to be extra helpful - leave a comment explaining why the answer is wrong.

For when to use the Not an Answer flag, [read this official post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).