# Why can't I flag this answer as VLQ despite it having no upvotes?

Tags: support, flags

My question is related to [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284803/why-cant-i-flag-this-answer-as-vlq). In that case, the accepted answer states that an answer couldn't be flagged as VLQ because the answer was upvoted; however, in this case, the answer has a negative score. It seems like the lack of an ability to flag it as VLQ is more age-related than the presence of anything redeeming about the answer:
[image]

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290744