# Is it ever acceptable to flag VLQ answers that "slipped through the cracks" for moderator attention?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

Related: [Why can't I flag this answer as VLQ despite it having no upvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350969/why-cant-i-flag-this-answer-as-vlq-despite-it-having-no-upvotes)

So, for a variety of reasons, you're not allowed to flag answers as VLQ after a certain length of time. That being the case, if there's an obviously VLQ answer that shouldn't be flagged as NAA, is it ever appropriate to flag it for moderator intervention? In this case, [the answer that makes me think of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25037574/4032703) *is* causing some harm because the fact that it's accepted means that [an obviously off-topic question won't Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816432/htc-one-m8-video-record-glitch). (The answer is VLQ because it's link-only).

In case this question or answer is deleted:
[image]

Comment: Flagging that answer as NAA is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Well, three of us took out the trash manually. The real feature request here should be to tweak the Roomba criteria so that a preponderance of downvotes on a question can override acceptance, at least with a no-score answer.

Comment: @CodyGray stats on [“desperate accept” answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291732/839601) provided by Shog made me feel like 20K deletion for these is a tolerable approach (even though back then I really hoped to get stats to support making them eligible for Roomba:)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Does that hold for all link-only answers like that? (The reason I ask is that the link *might*, in fact, technically answer the question, but obviously the answer is pretty terrible and should be deleted, especially given that it would've kept an otherwise-bad question from being deleted in Roomba).

Comment: @EJoshuaS: From my [when to flag as NAA post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer/265553#265553): *The rule-of-thumb here is to strip the markup; if you can still regard it as an (attempted) answer without the link, it is still an answer and should not be flagged.*. Here the inverse is true, strip the markup and there is nothing useful left. Although I would prefer a custom flag, a NAA flag would be honoured there, as it'll help get rid of the crap.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That makes sense.